# 'on the web' drupal module showing images on localhost but not remote host

Tags: drupal

the simple little module titled 'on the web' for drupal shows social network links. It links to some images on the directory. on my localhost install they are showing but in the remote install the img tags aren't even appearing. I looked in the   module's files and the path isn't hard-coded or anything so it's not to do with that.

any ideas?

the module is here: http://drupalmodules.com/module/on-the-web

cheers

andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was some weird stuff going on with case sensitivity on the file name and the server, so i fixed it by changing that.

Answer (score 0):

The coder of the module is a willing to receive info about the plugin if anyone has any problems. It would be cool if it was extended to include more social network badges and the ability to add more than 5.